# How can I take picturebox's screen shot with scale

Tags: c#, graphics

Picturebox's image exceeding the resolution
how can I take the whole Picturebox's screenshot with scale?

[image]

Comment: Why would you screenshot a picturebox rather than just going to the source?

Comment: I will use this screen shot into a document page which is printdocument1@John

Comment: I mean, why would you take a screenshot of a PictureBox? If it's displaying an image, why not use the image? If you're drawing it in the Paint event, why not use the same code to draw it on the PrintDocument?

Comment: Oh yeah I gotcha I have tried that, but I didn't get a success because values going through null to document form than I searched another solution @John

Comment: _Paint event, why not use the same code_ - _I have tried that, but I didn't get a success_ - Try again!. You could (but should not) temporarily enlarge the picturebox for the DrawImage call, but the best quality will always be custom code in the DrawPage event.

Comment: Okay, I will, thank you for the encouragement @TaW